# Indices in energy-momentum tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Let's assume next Lagrangian: 
$$\mathcal{L}=\partial_0\phi + \partial_0\psi^*+\nabla \phi \nabla \phi^*$$

and try to derive energy-momentum tensor:

$$T^{\mu \nu}=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_{\mu} \phi)}\partial^{\nu} \phi + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_{\mu} \phi^*)}\partial^{\nu} \phi^*-\eta^{\mu \nu }\mathcal{L}$$

$$T^{00}=\partial^0\phi+\partial^0\phi^*-\partial_0\phi+\partial_0\phi^*-\nabla \phi\nabla \phi^*=\nabla \phi\nabla \phi^*$$

$$T^{0i}=\partial^i\phi+\partial^i\phi^*$$
$$T^{i0}=\nabla\phi \partial^0\phi^*+\nabla\phi^* \partial^0\phi$$
$$T^{ij}=\nabla\phi \partial^j\phi^*+\nabla\phi^* \partial^j\phi$$

I know that $\nabla =\partial_i$

Then: 
$$T^{i0}=\partial_i\phi \partial^0\phi^*+\partial_i\phi^* \partial^0\phi$$
$$T^{ij}=\partial_i\phi \partial^j\phi^*+\partial_i\phi^* \partial^j\phi$$

Indices in last two lines bother me a lot.

As far as I understand $T^{ij}=a^ib^j$,
but in this case $T^{ij}=a_ib^j$, which contradicts with everything I have seen so far.

How to solve this weird indices problem?

Comment: Hint: Raise & lower indices with the metric.

Comment: @Qmechanic just like $T^{ij}=-(\partial^i\phi\partial^j\phi^*+\partial^i\phi^*\partial^j\phi)$?

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating 
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \varphi_\mu}
$$
for 
$$
L= \frac 12 \partial_\nu\varphi \partial^\nu\equiv \frac 12 g_{\mu\nu} \partial^\mu \varphi \partial^\nu \varphi  
$$
gives  $\partial^\mu \varphi$. In other words differentiating with respect to field with a *downstairs* index results in a tensor with an *upstairs* index.

Answer (score 0):

The contradiction arises as the Lagrangian is formulated in a non-tensorial form. Therefore you can not apply the tensor formalism.